# How to import folder which contains csv file in R Studio?

Tags: r

I have a file called "data" which consists of 330 cvs files.If i import, i can't import entire folder.It shows me to select one by one.Help me how to import that entire folder in r studio.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/importing-multiple-csv-files-into-r . I assume by "entire folder" you mean all csv files that exist there.

Comment: It would help if you posted the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

something like that should do it

```
setwd("where is your folder")
#
#List file subdirectories
folders<- list.files(path = "yourfolder")
#
#Get all files...
files <- rep(NA,0)
for(i in c(1:length(folders))) 
{
  files.i <- list.files(path = noquote(paste("yourfolder/",folders[i], "/", sep = ""))) 
  n <- length(files.i)
  files.i <- paste(folders[i], files.i, sep = "/")
  files <- c(files, files.i)
} 
# 
#
#Read first data file (& add file name as separate column)
T1 <- read.delim(paste("yourfolder/", files[1], sep = ""), sep = "", header=TRUE)
T1 <- cbind(T1, "FileName" = files[1])
```

Comment: I think this will do what you want.

Comment: library(data.table)
setwd("C:/your_files/")

WD="C:/your_files/"
data<-data.table(read.csv(text="Name,Address,Age,Work"))

csv.list<- list.files(WD)
k=1

for (i in csv.list){
  temp.data<-read.csv(i)
  data<-data.table(rbind(data,temp.data))

  if (k %% 100 == 0)
    print(k/length(csv.list))

  k<-k+1
}